# How to render QuickBlox VideoStream into opponentVideoView and ownVideoView?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I have to accept video call(QuickBlox) anywhere from the application. for this I have create a singleton class in which I have implemented few Quick Blox delegate method for receiving call. after receiving call i present user to VideoCallController. But I am unable to render VideoStream into opponanenVideoView and myVideoView. Can anyone suggest me where I have to set VideoChat Property either in Singleton or VideoCallController.

```
self.videoChat.viewToRenderOpponentVideoStream = opponentVideoView; 
self.videoChat.viewToRenderOwnVideoStream = myVideoView;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session didReceiveRemoteVideoTrack:(QBRTCVideoTrack *)videoTrack fromUser:(NSNumber *)userID
- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session didReceiveLocalVideoTrack:(QBRTCVideoTrack *)videoTrack
```

This delegate methods will be called after

```
- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session connectedToUser:(NSNumber *)userID
```

and

```
- (void)didReceiveNewSession:(QBRTCSession *)session userInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios